# how to install samsung firmware

Tags: 15.10

what possibility is to get odin mode in ubuntu like a apps to install like a windows os. Because i  like ubuntu but it is very difficult to flash  samsung firmware. Thanks to ubuntu community.

Comment: Odin mode? May you be referring to the Odin software from Samsung? If you're, install Heimdall from your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Odin is a Windows-only software.

As xangua suggested in the comments, you can use `Heimdall` as a replacement. I can confirm it worked to flash TWRP onto my S3.

Comment: yes but odin is very simple for using i am not smart with terminal comand. perhaps here is my problem because i want to install only ubuntu 15.10 in my pc. thanks for help.

Comment: Heimdall has a GUI as well. You have to install separately. Frontend & cli need to be installed for it to work